# C - Char to ASCII: 'a' prints as 6

Tags: c, ascii

I've been trying to convert char to ascii within C. I have noticed that when entering a character like 'a' instead of the program printing 'a', 97 it prints 6, 54. For some reason it's taking my input of 'a' as 6 and I'm not sure why.

Code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(int _nArgs, char _cArgs[MAX])
{
    printf("%c, %i", _cArgs[1], _cArgs[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want `argv[1][0]`  ... after fixing the signature of `main`.

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid `main` to me. Why did you write it this way? You want `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: I see the reason for a close vote, but not a downvote. The question is clear (even if the OP is confused a bit), and includes a MCVE. I've seen *much* worse. Be a bit more welcoming to a new contributor.

Comment: You should always turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 4):

You've defined your `main` function incorrectly.

You can define `main` as:

```
int main(void) {
    /* ... */
}
```

or as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

or equivalent (or in some implementation-defined manner, but don't worry about that).

You've defined the second parameter of `main` as an array of `char`, which is adjusted to type `char*`. It needs to be `char**` or `char *[]`. (And the `MAX` in the declaration is quietly ignored.)

You *can* use whatever names you like for the parameters, but `argc` and `argv` are conventional, and there's no good reason to use anything else.

Once you've fixed that, you can refer to the first character of the first command-line argument as `argv[1][0]`. (`argv[0]` points to a string that represents the name of the program.)

And you should print a newline `\n` at the end of your output.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already say, the signature of your `main` function is wrong. You should define `main` as follows:

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // your application code
    return 0;
}
```

The return type of `int` is not enforced by the compiler, `void` is usually accepted, too (there are long discussions on SO, `gcc` and `clang` both accept it though; C++ requires an `int` return type for `main`). It's bad practice to use a `void` return type though (as mentioned in the comments), so stick to `int`.

**BUT**: The *arguments* that `main` takes are either `void` or the combination of an `int` and a `char **argv` (which is the equivalent of `char *argv[]`). Thus, your second argument to `main` is missing another level of indirection, it should be a pointer to a pointer to `char`. Fix that and you'll be fine, even though declaring the second argument of `main` as a fixed size array is more than odd to me and I would not recommend to do that. Also, try to stick to the naming convention of `argc` and `argv` as they're what people expect when they read your code.

Comment: No, `void` is not okay. Some compilers might permit it, might even document that they permit it, but `void main` is not portable, and there's no good reason to use it. Also, an array is not "basically" a pointer; arrays are not pointers at all.

Comment: I'm not saying that an array is a pointer, though. I'm trying to explain to the OP what the mistake was. Obviously, we are talking about an array parameter here and arrays are passed to functions as pointers. I'm note sure if being nitpicky with an answer to such a basic question is helpful on any level.